# linux x86 tcp bind shellcode (GAS syntax) bind() does not return zero

Tags: linux, sockets, assembly, gnu-assembler, shellcode

i'm trying to make a tcp bind shellcode on linux x86 architecture and i'm using GAS syntax.
i could successfully call socketcall(SYS_SOCKET) and got a file descriptor (which is not NULL)
now that im trying to use that fd and make a SYS_BIND call i seem to get a return value from bind which is not ZERO (which it should be) . i've already debugged it . everything is just on the stack but ...

here is the commented code :

```
.text

.globl _start

_start:

    xorl %eax, %eax
    xorl %ebx, %ebx
    movb $1, %bl
    subl $30, %esp
    movl %esp, %esi

# array of arguments for socketcall->SYS_SOCKET:

    movb $2, 8(%esi)
    movb $1, 12(%esi)
    movl %eax, 16(%esi)

# load the address of that array in ecx:

    leal 8(%esi), %ecx
    movb $102, %al

    int $0x80

    jz exit0 # exit(0) if eax(return value)==0
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

bind:

    movl %eax, %edx       # save the file descriptor
    xorl %eax, %eax
    inc %bl               # bl == 2 -> bind

    movw $2, 8(%esi)      # sa_family == AF_INET
    movw $2222, 10(%esi)  # sin_port == 2222

    movl %eax, 12(%esi)   # INADDR_ANY
    movl %eax, 16(%esi)   # sin_zero
    movl %eax, 20(%esi)   # sin_zero

    addl $16, %eax        
    pushl %eax            # size of struct sockaddr(16) as the third argument of bind,pushed first
    leal 8(%esi), %ecx    # leal the address of argument array into ecx
    pushl %ecx            # push it onto the stack
    pushl %edx            # file descriptor (first argument)
    movb $102, %al        # socketcall

    int $0x80

    jnz exit1 # exit(1) if bind() return value is not zero (zero flag is not set)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

exit0:
    xorl %eax, %eax
    inc %eax
    xorl %ebx, %ebx

    int $0x80

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------

exit1:
    xorl %eax, %eax
    inc %eax
    xorl %ebx, %ebx
    inc %ebx

    int $0x80
```

compiled:

```
as -ggstabs -o sys_socket.o sys_socket.s
```

linked:

```
ld -o sys_socket sys_socket.o
```

STACK and Registers just before the last kernel interrupt (GDB) :

```
(gdb) x/8xw $esp
0xbffff5d6: 0x00000007  0xbffff5ea  0x00000010  0x00000000
0xbffff5e6: 0x00000000  0x08ae0002  0x00000000  0x00000000
(gdb) x/1xb 0xbffff5ea
0xbffff5ea: 0x02
(gdb) i r
eax            0xfffffff7   -9
ecx            0xbffff5ea   -1073744406
edx            0x7  7
ebx            0x2  2
esp            0xbffff5d6   0xbffff5d6
ebp            0x0  0x0
esi            0xbffff5e2   -1073744414
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x8048099    0x8048099 <bind+40>
eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
(gdb)
```

so where is the problem and how to solve it exactly ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assemble the argument array on the stack, but you need to pass the address for the system call to use. You should clean up your code a little, it's hard to follow what you are doing. As a quick hack, `movl %esp, %ecx` before `int $0x80` seems to work, although not sure if you wanted this:

```
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44552), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
```

Also note that `jz` and `jnz` do not compare `eax` to `0` automatically, that is you can't use them directly after `int $0x80`. They just test the zero flag. You have to add code to set it based on `eax` yourself, such as `testl %eax, %eax`.

Furthermore, you should really keep the stack pointer 4 bytes aligned. `subl $30, %esp` is a very bad idea.

---

For this call, you need 2 things in memory. One, the argument array. You need to pass a pointer to that in `ecx`. Two, the second argument itself has to be a pointer to a `sockaddr` struct.

You build the sockaddr in memory pointed to by `esi+8`. Your comment incorrectly says that's the argument array, but it isn't. You build the argument array by the 3 `push` instructions on the stack, subsequently. As such the address of the argument array is `esp`, and the value at `esp+4` (the second argument) points to `esi+8` which is your sockaddr. You misleadingly use `esi+8` (the first 8 bytes are unused there), but at least it's consistent and you have enough memory allocated, so it happens to work.

Also note that the port number is expected to be in network (big endian) byte order, that's why your `2222` (`=0x08AE`) will be interpreted as `44552` (`=0xAE08`).

Comment: thanks for your advice. got your point about jz and subl . i'm loading the address of argument array into ecx and passing it to socketcall together with SYS_BIND(2) and then calling the interrupt. i've pushed everything onto the stack and also pushed 102 into eax then called the interrupt. didn't get your point where you said :`you need to pass the address for the system call to use.` can you explain it a little more please.

Comment: and yupp !!! thanks for your great explanation . now i understand why it didn't work . i mean i should have moved the file descriptor in `esi+24` and `leal 8(%esi), %ecx` and then `movl %ecx, 28(%esi)` then load the address of `esi+24` into `%ecx` and so on ... i'm marking your answer as the solution . again thanks for your analysis and explanation. kind regards...